# What is the shorthand for this converge and pair?

Tags: javascript, ramda.js

```
R.converge(R.pair, [
  R.filter(x => x & 1),
  R.reject(x => x & 1)
])
```

Is there an easier in-library way to do this split of odd and even numbers?

I'm specifically interested in a Ramda solution (rather than creating a new function) which accepts a function for the divide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Update

The below was silly.  There's a much better solution in [`partition`](http://ramdajs.com/docs/#partition), which I'd temporarily forgotten.

```
 partition(n => n & 1, [8, 6, 7, 5, 3, 0, 9]); //=> [[7, 5, 3, 9], [8, 6, 0]]
```

This also restores your original order.

---

### Original, superceded, answer

[`groupBy`](http://ramdajs.com/docs/#groupBy) is probably the closest. `groupBy(modulo(__, 2))` will get you close.

But its output is somewhat different from yours.   You can compose this with [`values`](http://ramdajs.com/docs/#values) to get one much like your version:

```
const parties = compose(values, groupBy(modulo(__, 2)))
parities([8, 6, 7, 5, 3, 0, 9]); //=> [[8, 6, 0], [7, 5, 3, 9]]
```

You can see this in action on the **[Ramda Repl](http://ramdajs.com/repl/#?compose%28values%2C%20groupBy%28modulo%28__%2C%202%29%29%29%28%5B8%2C%206%2C%207%2C%205%2C%203%2C%200%2C%209%5D%29%0A%0Apartition%28n%20%3D%3E%20n%20%26%201%2C%20%5B8%2C%206%2C%207%2C%205%2C%203%2C%200%2C%209%5D%29%0A)**.

Comment: I like it, it solves repeating the function. I feel like z => compose(values, z)  is almost it, but I would want something a bit more "truthy" rather than "groupy". If that makes sense??? P.S I know who you are, and I'm honoured that you responded Sir.

Comment: It is more simple, plus you are Scott Sauyet so "correct answer" it is.

Comment: However... f => 
R.converge(R.pair, [
  R.filter(f),
  R.reject(f)
]); Has advantages.

Comment: Updated with a much better answer.  Such a function is actually built-in to Ramda.

Comment: BTW, although I'm a co-founder of Ramda, there are many people who know it as well or better.

Comment: Also, of course using R.values is dangerous as it doesn't guarantee the same order.

Comment: I massively endorse (although I don't favour performance as an absolute)  Scott's eventual use of n => n & 1 instead of modulo. Wholly because of this extract from their website / mantra .... "Last but not least, Ramda strives for performance. A reliable and quick implementation wins over any notions of functional purity."

Comment: (accidentally flagged the above comment).